# Как сохранить каждую запись в Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

Привет, я пытаюсь написать приложение на Swift и использую Realm. Приложение что то типо фитнесс трекера. Вот моя модель данных:

```
class Meditation: Object {


   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var count = 0
   dynamic var targetAmount = 0
   dynamic var malasStep = 108
   dynamic var id = 0
   dynamic var imageName = ""
   dynamic var date = NSDate()

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
```

Мне нужно в статистике отобразить количество(count) и дату. То есть за каждый день. Например 15.10.2016 -- 200, 16.10.2016 -- 100. Но в БД сохраняется сумма(300). И я не могу отобразить количество за каждый день.

Подскажите может как то можно сохранять все в одну сущность но так что бы каждое сохранение поля count и date можно было отобразить.

Comment: Можно пример кода, где вы сохраняете/считываете записи из БД? Такое чувство, что у вас все записи сохраняются в одну, отсюда и сумма

Answer (score 2):

Сори, сразу не подумал что бы скинуть.
Вот одна кнопка

```
@IBAction func add108(_ sender: UIButton) {

    totalCount += 108

    countOfmeditationLabelUI.text = String(totalCount)

    try! realm.write {
         currentMeditation.count = totalCount
         currentMeditation.date = NSDate()
         realm.add(currentMeditation)
    }
```

Вот вторая

```
 @IBAction func addMore(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add more", message: "Enter a count", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {[weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields?[0]

        self.totalCount += Int((textField?.text)!)!
        self.countOfmeditationLabelUI.text = String(self.totalCount)

        try! realm.write {
            self.currentMeditation.count = self.totalCount
            realm.add(self.currentMeditation)
        }

    }))
```

И вот одна из 4х сущностей

```
let med1 = Meditation()
        med1.name = "Refuge"
        med1.count = 0
        med1.targetAmount = 111111
        med1.malasStep = 108
        med1.imageName = "refuge1.jpg"
        med1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то тут дело в том, что вы добавляете один и тот же объект self.currentMeditation, поэтому в БД происходит его обновление, а не добавление.

Чтобы добавить объект self.currentMeditation, нужно предварительно создать новый:

```
self.currentMeditation = Meditation()

try! realm.write {
     self.currentMeditation.id = 1
     self.currentMeditation.count = self.totalCount
     ...
     realm.add(self.currentMeditation)
}
```